# DataGridView per row styling

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have the below code on mouseEnter for the datagridview, it works, but its not ideal as well the grid isn't styled until the user moves the mouse over the grid. Also I would prefer the styling to be done as the row is being added to the grid, or at least soon as all rows have been added... just not familiar with datagridview and which events would best suited to use. Also if the users sorts a column it needs doing again?

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ModpacksGridView.Rows)
        {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "✓")
                {
                    ModpacksGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    ModpacksGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    ModpacksGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    ModpacksGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Which technology is this? Xaml? Add the tag :)

Comment: Use the CellFormatting event.

Comment: the language tag is already added... c#

Comment: Just tried the CellFormatting event.. seems to work nicely thanks